# Workstation file synchronization to deploy though a group policy

Tags: networking, group-policy, network-share, synchronization

I have roughly 20 PC i want to back up myDocuments folder to one of our servers.
Need some recommendations on a file sync program that i can deploy though a group policy.
And Looking for a work around to keep from configuring each pc to back up to a specific file on the server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not setup [redirected folders](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/232692) and combined that with [offline files](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307853).  Both can be configured via group policy.

Comment: This is really the best option.  We've been using folder redirection for years.  Nary a problem.  I can't say the same for offline files however...

Comment: Exactly what I was gonna suggest.  You can configure your redirection policy to move anything on the PC back to the server first time too.  I think offline files might be OK if you're happy to live within it's limitations (I've seen MS guys use it before and they seemed OK with it).  I wouldn't advise using it unless you *know* that you *have* to though.

Comment: Windows XP Offline Files screws up tremendously when redirected folders get above 2GB in size (these so-called "automatically pinned" folders). Folders the user chooses to replicate, or folders that are administatively "pinned" thorough Group Policy, don't act strangely when the 2GB limit is hit. If you can deal with this limitation (and if you can configure automatic sync at logon and logoff and can get users to reliably logoff or shutdown before leaving the office and logon again when returning) then it really does work pretty well.